# Javascript: convert a string containing date & time to a string in the UTC timezone

Tags: javascript

I have a string in the format below:

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm
```

This string is based on the timezone on the client browser.
I need to convert this to a string showing the time in UTC.

I can calculate how many hours the offset is using:

```
new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60
```

Which is fine if the time doesn't take it back by a day (eg. if there's a -2 hour offset to apply to a 1am time).

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Is [toUTCString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) not an option?

Answer (score 0):

With this code you could convert the date strings on client side to corresponding UTC time.

```js
let now = new Date()  // Thu Oct 28 2021 15:31:17 GMT+0200

// this Date in your given format would be >>

let dateStr = '2021-10-28 15:31'

let utcDate = new Date(dateStr).toUTCString()

console.log(utcDate) // Thu, 28 Oct 2021 13:31:00 GMT  << -02:00 to my local time above

let isoDate = new Date(dateStr).toISOString()

console.log(isoDate) // 2021-10-28T13:31:00.000Z  << better format for storing dates
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [luxon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/luxon) because you can do various things on it.

```
Import {DateTime} from "luxon";
DateTime.locale().setZone("your zone").fromFormat("2021-10-10 22:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").toUTC();
```

Hope it works cause wrote with my phone.